# How can I optimize my java implementation of Held-Karp algorithm to shorten the running time?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I use Java implemented Held-Karp[TSP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algo to solve a 25 cities TSP problem.
The program passes with 4 cities.

When it runs with 25 cities it won't stop for several hours. I use jVisualVM to see what's the hotspot, after some optimization now it shows
98% of time is in real computing instead in Map.contains or Map.get.

So I'd like to have your advice,  and here is the code:

```
    private void solve() throws Exception {
        long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int counter = 0;

        List<BitSetEndPointID> previousCosts;
        List<BitSetEndPointID> currentCosts;
        //maximum number of elements is c(n,[n/2])
        //To calculate m-set's costs just need to keep (m-1)set's costs
        List<BitSetEndPointID> lastKeys = new ArrayList<BitSetEndPointID>();
        int m;
        if (totalNodes < 10) {
            //for test data, generate them on the fly
            SetUtil3.generateMSet(totalNodes);
        }
        //m=1
        BitSet beginSet = new BitSet();
        beginSet.set(0);
        previousCosts = new ArrayList<BitSetEndPointID>(1);
        BitSetEndPointID beginner = new BitSetEndPointID(beginSet, 0);
        beginner.setCost(0f);
        previousCosts.add(beginner);

        //for m=2 to totalNodes
        for (m = 2; m <= totalNodes; m++) {// sum(m=2..n 's C(n,m)*(m-1)(m-1)) ==> O(n^2 * 2^n)
            //pick m elements from total nodes, the element id is the index of nodeCoordinates
            // the first node is always present

            BitSet[] msets;
            if (totalNodes < 10) {
                msets = SetUtil3.msets[m - 1];
            } else {
                //for real data set, will read from serialized file
                msets = SetUtil3.getMsets(totalNodes, m-1);
            }
            currentCosts = new ArrayList<BitSetEndPointID>(msets.length);
            //System.out.println(m + " sets' size: " + msets.size());
            for (BitSet mset : msets) { //C(n,m) mset
                int[] candidates = allSetBits(mset, m);
                //mset is a BitSet which makes sure begin point 0 comes first
                //so end point candidate begins with 1. candidate[0] is always begin point 0
                for (int i = 1; i < candidates.length; i++) { // m-1 bits are set
                    //set the new last point as j, j must not be the same as begin point 0
                    int j = candidates[i];
                    //middleNodes = mset -{j}
                    BitSet middleNodes = (BitSet) mset.clone();
                    middleNodes.clear(j);
                    //loop through all possible points which are second to the last
                    //and get min(A[S-{j},k] + k->j), k!=j
                    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
                    int k;
                    for (int ki = 0; ki < candidates.length; ki++) {// m-1 calculation
                        k = candidates[ki];
                        if (k == j) continue;
                        float middleCost = 0;
                        BitSetEndPointID key = new BitSetEndPointID(middleNodes, k);
                        int index = previousCosts.indexOf(key);
                        if (index != -1) {
                            //System.out.println("get value from  map in m " + m + " y key " + middleNodes);
                            middleCost = previousCosts.get(index).getCost();
                        } else if (k == 0 && !middleNodes.equals(beginSet)) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("middleCost not found!");
                            continue;
//                            System.exit(-1);
                        }


                        float lastCost = distances[k][j];
                        float cost = middleCost + lastCost;
                        if (cost < min) {
                            min = cost;
                        }

                        counter++;
                        if (counter % 500000 == 0) {
                            try {
                                Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                                System.out.println("Who dares interrupt my precious sleep?!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //set the costs for chosen mset and last point j
                    BitSetEndPointID key = new BitSetEndPointID(mset, j);
                    key.setCost(min);
                    currentCosts.add(key);

//                    System.out.println("===========================================>mset " + mset + " and end at " +
//                            j + " 's min cost: " + min);
//                    if (m == totalNodes) {
//                        lastKeys.add(key);
//                    }
                }
            }
            previousCosts = currentCosts;
            System.out.println("...");
        }

        calcLastStop(lastKeys, previousCosts);
        System.out.println(" cost " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime) / 60000 + " minutes.");
    }


    private void calcLastStop(List<BitSetEndPointID> lastKeys, List<BitSetEndPointID>  costs) {
        //last step, calculate the min(A[S={1..n},k] +k->1)
        float finalMinimum = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        for (BitSetEndPointID key : costs) {
            float middleCost = key.getCost();
            Integer endPoint = key.lastPointID;
            float lastCost = distances[endPoint][0];
            float cost = middleCost + lastCost;
            if (cost < finalMinimum) {
                finalMinimum = cost;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("final result: " + finalMinimum);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear, I mean there was lots of time spent on Map methods BEFORE my optimization. Now I am using Object[] to replace Map.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I agree with you and tried to make a similar vote, but it only gave me 5 options of where this question should migrate to.  This may be a silly question, but when you're flagging as off-topic, how can you specify which StackExchange group you want?

Comment: @Choirbean You have to write a custom comment.

Comment: @NicoSchertler No. The OP is not asking for a review, they're just trying to make it faster. Optimization is fully on-topic here.

Comment: @maaartinus This seems to be a controversial issue as observed in [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302873) and the linked questions. CodeReview Help states the following topics: *feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas: (...) Performance*. In my opinion, asking for significant algorithmic changes (or an entirely different algorithm) belongs on StackOverflow, whereas improvements to data layout and auxiliary data structures and the like belong on CodeReview. This question seems to be the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can speed up your code by using arrays of primitives (it's likely to have to better memory layout than a list of objects) and operating on bitmasks directly (without bitsets or other objects). Here is some code (it generates a random graph but you can easily change it so that it reads your graph):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    final static float INF = 1e10f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int n = 25;
        float[][] dist = new float[n][n];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                dist[i][j] = dist[j][i] = random.nextFloat();
        float[][] dp = new float[n][1 << n];
        for (int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++)
            Arrays.fill(dp[i], INF);
        dp[0][1] = 0.0f;
        for (int mask = 1; mask < (1 << n); mask++) {
            for (int lastNode = 0; lastNode < n; lastNode++) {
                if ((mask & (1 << lastNode)) == 0)
                    continue; 
                for (int nextNode = 0; nextNode < n; nextNode++) {
                    if ((mask & (1 << nextNode)) != 0)
                        continue;
                    dp[nextNode][mask | (1 << nextNode)] = Math.min(
                            dp[nextNode][mask | (1 << nextNode)],
                            dp[lastNode][mask] + dist[lastNode][nextNode]);
                }
            }   
        }
        double res = INF;
        for (int lastNode = 0; lastNode < n; lastNode++)
            res = Math.min(res, dist[lastNode][0] + dp[lastNode][(1 << n) - 1]);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

It takes only a couple of minutes to complete on my computer:

```
time java Main
...
real    2m5.546s
user    2m2.264s
sys     0m1.572s
```

Comment: It runs perfectly! Could you explain a little bit these questions?  1.What's the meaning of (mask & (1 << lastNode),  (mask & (1 << nextNode), mask | (1 << nextNode)                                                                                              2. How does the mask replace all of the BitSet?

Comment: @user1532146 The ith bit is set in mask if and only if ith node is already in the path.  The first two expressions check if the bit is set. The last one sets the bit that corresponds to the nextNode.

Comment: Hi! Could you please show how to interpret th eresults? The sequence?